# Spring : How to delete entry from junction table?

Tags: java, spring, repository, sql-delete, junction-table

I have a junction table of user_id and favorite_property_id And now I want to delete the favorite property of the user  , I tried the following method in repository but its not working , Does anybody have any idea that how can i delete he entry from junction table?

**User.java**

```
@Entity
    public class User implements Serializable, UserGetters {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Property> favouriteProperty;

    public Set<Property> getFavouriteProperty() {
            return favouriteProperty;
        }

        public void setFavouriteProperty(Set<Property> favouriteProperty) {
            this.favouriteProperty = favouriteProperty;
        }
        }
```

**UserRepository**

```
public interface UserRepository  extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
//@Transactional
     // Long deleteByFavouritePropertyId(@Param("favoriteProperty") Long favoriteProperty);

    // @Query("delete favouriteProperty from user u where u.favouriteProperty.id=:favouriteProperty")
    // void unmarkFavouriteProperty(@Param("favouriteProperty")  Long favouriteProperty);

}
```

Comment: Unexpected Token : from near line 1, column 26 [delete favouriteProperty from user u where u.favouriteProperty.id=:favouriteProperty] @Afridi

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like:

### 1. Load user object

```
User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);
```

### 2. Remove required object from list

```
user.getFavouriteProperty().remove(id);
```

### 3. Save User Object

```
userRepository.save(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("delete Category where id = :favorite_property_id ");
query.setParameter("favorite_property_id ", new Long(favoriteProperty));
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

in your repository file. It will work fine.

Comment: What is session ?

Comment: Its the hibernate session acquired from session factory. 
`Session sess = factory.openSession();`

Comment: THanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This was so simple :P

I can delete by using following API

API : http://localhost:8555/api/users/2/favouriteProperty/3

METHOD : DELETE